# Indent (margin, padding) between elements (css)

Tags: html, css, margin, padding, indentation

I've faced a problem: there is a flex wrapper which has style

```
justify-content: space-between
```

and

```
flex-wrap: wrap
```

I want left button, right button and text block to have some space between before wrapping. And after right button's transition on the next line there won't be any indentation on the "border" side. Hope you understand.

```css
.long-line {
    max-width: 400px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid;
}
button {
    background: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="long-line">
  <div class="left-item"><button>Big left button</button></div>
  <div class="center-item">more and more text</div>
  <div class="right-item"><button>right button</button></div>
</div>
```

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykxcI.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtyXj.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/80JbP.png
```

Comment: try `justify-content:  space-evenly;`

Comment: @ShivKumarBaghel it still looks the same as on the 2nd screenshot. I need no margin of the element after transition on next line. Please look at the screenshots

Comment: you code seems to be fine, like the images

Comment: @TemaniAfif I know. There are screenshots of my code in different window's sizes. I need to prevent this sticking together by making some space between elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one of possible solutions:
1) remove padding from "long-line";
2) wrap buttons in divs;
3) add padding to "long-line"'s children.

```css
.long-line {
    max-width: 400px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid;
}

.long-line > div {
    padding: 10px;
}

button {
    background: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="long-line">
    <div class="left-item"><button>Big left button</button></div>
    <div class="center-item">more and more text</div>
    <div class="right-item"><button>right button</button></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can give margin to the center text div so that it does not stick to the border. Also top margin to the button incase they are getting stuck at some viewpoints.

Comment: but when the "parent" will get smaller it will go over next line and and will have more space from left border than buttons. Sorry that hadn't mentioned it before.